# Mercurial ignores color extension when an output template is specified

Tags: mercurial, colors

How do I get the mercurial color extension to work when a style (including the default) is specified on the command line or in `~/.hgrc`?

My `~/.hgrc` looks like

```
[extensions]
color=
[color]
log.changeset=yellow
```

When I do `hg log` the changeset lines are highlighted in yellow, as expected, e.g.

```
changeset:   399:c42d2627824f <----- THIS LINE IS IN YELLOW :-)
user:        A User <user@example.com>
date:        Tue Jun 21 11:07:17 2011 +0200
summary:     add code to rm -rf /
```

However, if I do `hg log --style=default`, the output is identical but the changeset lines are no longer highlighted.

You may say, "well, don't specify `--style=default`!"

Unfortunately this is a problem because my goal is to tweak the default template. I made a copy of the template, called it map-cmdline.default2 and whether I do `hg log --style=default2` or add `style=default2` to my `~/.hgrc`, the color highlighting is disabled.

Comment: Might be worth an [issue](http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've discovered that Mercurial "cheats": `hg log` does not use the template system, the output is hard-coded. The `--style` flag triggers the slower (but customizable) template engine.

Changing this would probably be difficult, but I agree with Oben that you should open an issue about this.